# Javascript/jquery scoring broken on clicking game

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a simple game where when you click on the correct/incorrect picture, the picture then switches and adds/subtracts points. My code works when only clicking in one div, but when another div is added, the points seem to randomly go up and down.
Here's my code:

```
var score=0;
function randomImg() 
{

var myimages=new Array();

myimages[0]="mozzarella.png";
myimages[1]="target.jpg";
myimages[2]="badtarget.jpg";
myimages[3]="badtarget2.jpg";

var w=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
var x=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
var y=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
var z=Math.floor(Math.random()*4);

document.getElementById("target2").src=myimages[w];
document.getElementById("target").src=myimages[x];
document.getElementById("badtarget").src=myimages[y];
document.getElementById("badtarget2").src=myimages[z];

if (x==0)
{
$('#target').one("click", function(){
    $('#output').html(++score);
});
}

else if (x==1)
{
$('#target').one("click", function(){
    $('#output').html(++score);
});
}

else if (x==2)
{
$('#target').one("click", function(){
    $('#output').html(--score);
});
}

else if (x==3)
{
$('#target').one("click", function(){
    $('#output').html(--score);
});
}

if (w==0)
{
$('#target2').one("click", function(){
    $('#output').html(++score);
});
}

else if (w==1)
{
$('#target2').one("click", function(){
    $('#output').html(++score);
});
}

else if (w==2)
{
$('#target2').one("click", function(){
    $('#output').html(--score);
});
}

else if (w==3)
{
$('#target2').one("click", function(){
    $('#output').html(--score);
});
}

}
```

Comment: By `one()` do you mean `on()`?

Comment: Put this is a fiddle

Comment: each time you call `randomImg()` you are binding a new click event to the elements - you need to unbind any previously bound events first otherwise anything that hasn't been clicked will have 2 events bound to them, which is probably the cause of your random scores

Comment: @WesFoster I think OP is meaning to use `one` - they are meaning to only bind one click event to the element as they are wanting to bind a new event after that click.  They just forgot that all the other unclicked elements still have their event bound to them

Comment: Need HTML. I have a suspicion that you might have duplicated ids perhaps?

Comment: @Pete I think that is my issue but I'm not sure how I would unbind each event that isn't used

Comment: @idkwhatimdoing you can use [`.unbind`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) or [`.off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: @Pete I got it thanks for the help